# Why is IF: not properly evaluating this variable?

Tags: python-2.7

I've created a function that creates another variable based on the arguments that are passed to it.

As below:

```
def process_command(var1, var2, var3, var4):
  if var3 == ":help":
    reply = 'Help command received.'
  if var3 == ':status':
    reply = 'Status command received.'
  if var3 == ':start':
    reply = 'Start command received.'
 if var3 == ':stop':
    reply = 'Stop command received.'
  if var3 == ':shutdown':
    reply = 'Shutdown command received.'
  else:
    reply = '%s command unknown.\nSend :help for a list of commands.' % msg
```

When my program assigns `:help` (or any of the others) to `var3` and calls this function, it skips straight to the `ELSE:` line instead of working on the expected `if var3 == ':help':` line.

My first thought was that there was an issue using a colon in the text, so I removed it - same result.  It doesn't see `'help'` or `':help'` in this function.

When I pass it with `var3` assigned as ':help' it processes the else statement and responds with:

```
:help command unknown.
Send :help for a list of commands.
```

I've tried forcing it to be a `str()` just in case, that didn't work either.  I tried slicing out the colon, no dice.

Why this isn't seeing my variable assigned as `':help'` when it appears to be set to exactly that?

Comment: Step through your code... line by line... and you will see the light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want every single `if` statement to be run, use `elif`. Otherwise, every one will be called.

```
foo = True
if foo:
    print 'yes'
    #Gets called
if not foo:
    print 'no'
else:
    print 'yes' #Also gets called
```

Basically, your code was reaching the `reply = 'Help command received.'`, but then it went to `if var3 == ':shutdown':`, which then triggered the `else`, reassigning `reply`.

Here is your updated code:

```
def process_command(var1, var2, var3, var4):
  if var3 == ":help":
    reply = 'Help command received.'
  elif var3 == ':status':
    reply = 'Status command received.'
  elif var3 == ':start':
    reply = 'Start command received.'
  elif var3 == ':stop':
    reply = 'Stop command received.'
  elif var3 == ':shutdown':
    reply = 'Shutdown command received.'
  else:
    reply = '%s command unknown.\nSend :help for a list of commands.' % msg
```

Comment: Very thorough answer.  Thank you for walking through __what__ was happening and not just telling me what to do.

Answer (score 3):

`if` statements are always evaluated when they are reached. If you want the condition to be evaluated only if the previous condition failed then you need to use `elif` instead.

```
if ...:
   ...
elif ...:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Comment: Mmmmmm.  That there is some damned tasty humble pie.